# if else statement syntax error in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
#--------------input-------------#
def getmove():
    global room,posx,posy,moves,dead,inventory,foods,drinks,food,water
    move=input()
    if move == 'e':
        posx=posx+1
    if move == 'w':
        posx=posx-1
    if move == 's':
        posy=posy+1
    if move == 'n':
        posy=posy-1
    if 'grab' in move:
        additem(move,inventory)
    if move == 'inventory':
        print(inventory)
    if move == 'save':
        moves-=1
        food+=1
        water+=1
        save(posx,posy,moves,dead,food,water)
    if move == 'load_save':
        moves-=1
        food+=1
        water+=1
        load_save()
    if move == 'search':
        search(inventory)
    if move == 'eat':
        food+=4
        eat()
    if move == 'drink':
        water+=4
        drink()
    if food <= 2:
        print('You start to feel hungry')
    if water <=2:
        print('You start to feel thirsty')
    if food == 0 or water == 0:
        dead = True
        seeifdead(room,posx,posy,moves,dead,inventory,foods,drinks)
    moves+=1
    food-=1
    water-=1
    else:
        print('I dont understand')
        moves-=1
        food+=1
        water+=1
    #print(posx,posy,moves,dead)
    getroom(posx,posy,moves,dead,room)
    #print(posx,posy,moves,dead)
    getmove()
```

I wrote a python program back in college for a basic game and it was working but now a few years later it stopped working and I don't see any issues in it

when I run the program it complains about invalid syntax on the else statement but I don't see anything wrong with it but then again I've had an almost two-year break from programming, in general. Can someone please help me understand what I did wrong?

Also if needed I can add the whole program this is just the part for input

thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: Indentation matters in Python. The `else` is lonely lying around here.

Comment: You can't have code between your if and the preceding else that's not inside the if statement

Comment: how its the else statement indented wrong? i thought it was supposed to be lined up with the if statements?

Comment: im going to give that a try ninesalt thank you so much

Comment: The `else` is correctly indented but the lines above aren't.

Comment: that was the problem ninesalt thank you im gonna see if i can close this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of the code:

```
if food == 0 or water == 0:
    dead = True
    seeifdead(room,posx,posy,moves,dead,inventory,foods,drinks)
moves+=1
food-=1
water-=1
else:
    print('I dont understand')
    moves-=1
    food+=1
    water+=1
```

You have code between your `if` and its corresponding `else`.
This will lead to a syntax error.

```
if food == 0 or water == 0:
    dead = True
    seeifdead(room,posx,posy,moves,dead,inventory,foods,drinks)
    moves+=1
    food-=1
    water-=1
else:
    print('I dont understand')
    moves-=1
    food+=1
    water+=1
```

Compare it with the code above and see the difference.