# Why is there a syntax error for else even though it is at the same indent with if?

Tags: python

The following program calculates the number of input strings with letter ‘a’, and end the program when the input string is “####”. Here is an expected sample run:

```
while True:
    string = input("enter a string (enter #### to stop): ")
    count = 0
    for letter in string:
        if letter == 'a':
            break
        count +=1
        else:
            pass

output:
File "<ipython-input-53-4d8a4c435ab9>", line 8
    else:
       ^
Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Your `else` block doesn't follow `if` block. There is `count += 1` between them.

Comment: the `if` loop is considered broken at the `count += 1` line - move it before the `if` statement and it'll work.

Comment: Why are us `break`ing when input is `a`? Correct the `count` indentation and move `break`

Comment: And  that `else: pass` is totally useless. Just remove it.

Comment: This looks weirdly familiar... Is this code snippet from some guide or something? I swear I saw someone post the exact same issue recently, like same code and everything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this if else statement giving a syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488393/why-is-this-if-else-statement-giving-a-syntax-error)

Answer (score 1):

Let's break your code:

```py
    if letter == 'a':
        break
    count +=1
    else:
        pass
```

When the letter 'a' is found the conditional method is escaped and nothing happens.

You have added `count += 1`  out of indentation to the if statement, So the interpreter thinks that the if statement is over and you are writing other code there.
Your interpreter looks your code like this:

```
if letter=='a':
   break
```

This is one block of code for comparing the letter.

```
count += 1
```

After escaping from the if statement the flow of code goes here and count is increased by 1.

```
else:
   pass
```

Why am I getting an else statement without any if statement?

So you should do something like this:

```
if letter=='a':
   count += 1 
   break
else:
   pass
```

There shouldn't be indentation for the count if you want to count the no. of letter 'a's present in the string.

Comment: also the break statement is going to break the loop so you'll never count past 1...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have added `count +=1` after the if, not else.

Change this:

```
    string = input("enter a string (enter #### to stop): ")
    count = 0
    for letter in string:
        if letter == 'a':
            break
        count +=1
        else:
            pass
```

To:

```
while True:
    string = input("enter a string (enter #### to stop): ")
    count = 0
    for letter in string:
        if letter == 'a':
            break
        count +=1
```

It works!